# MYSQL: Getting existing primary key when inserting record with duplicate unique key?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I've got a mysql database with a table that has both a auto-increment primary key and unique string valued key (a sha-1 hash).

If I try to add a record that has the same sha-1 hash as an existing record, I just want to get the primary key of the existing record. I can use something like "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" or "INSERT IGNORE" to prevent an exception when trying to insert a record with a existing hash value.

However, when that happens, I need to retrieve the primary key of the existing record. I can't find a way to do that with a single SQL statement. If it matters, my code is in Java and I'm using JDBC.

Alternatively, I can do it with two statements (either a query followed by an insertion if not found, or a insertion followed by a query if a duplicate key exists). But I presume a single statement would be more efficient.

Comment: for what do you need "to retrieve the primary key of the existing record"?

Comment: You can't do it with a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

> If I try to add a record that has the same sha-1 hash as an existing
>   record, I just want to get the primary key of the existing record. I
>   can use something like "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" or "INSERT
>   IGNORE" to prevent an exception when trying to insert a record with a
>   existing hash value.

If you have an `UNIQUE` index on a column, no matter what you tried, the RDMS will *not* allow duplicates in that column (except for the `NULL` value).

As you said, there is solution to prevent "error" if this appends. Probably `INSERT IGNORE` in your case.

Anyway, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` modify the database. MySQL *never* return values for these statements. The only way to read your DB is to use a `SELECT` statement.

---

Here the "workaround" is simple, since you have an `UNIQUE` column:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl (pk, sha_key) VALUES ( ... ), ( ... );
SELECT pk, sha_key FROM tbl WHERE sha_key IN ( ... );
--                                             ^^^
--             Here the list of the sha1 keys you *tried* to insert
```

Comment: Your assertion that `INSERT` and `UPDATE` never return values is not entirely true. Some databases (eg [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-insert.html), [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-insert.html#langrefupd25-insert-returning)) support something like `INSERT ... RETURNING columnname[, columnname]`, even on [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right. I was speaking mostly about MySQL since this is how the question was tagged. But I will edit my answer to be more accurate about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is exactly the right statement to use in your situation. When you use ON DUPLICATE, if the insert happens without duplicate, JDBC returns count of 1 and the ID of the newly inserted row. If the action taken is an update due to duplicate, JDBC returns count of 2 and both the ID of the original row AND the newly generated ID, even though the new ID is never actually inserted into the table.

You can get the correct key by calling PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys(). The first key is pretty much always the one you are interested in. For this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
```

You can get the inserted or updated ID by calling:

```
Long key;
ResultSet keys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (keys.next())
    key = keys.getLong("GENERATED_KEY");
```